# memcopy()やmemclear()のようなものは無いのでしょうか。

Tags: swift

```
class Test : NSObject {
   var testUint8: UInt8 = 0x00
   var testNSNumber: NSNumber = NSNumber(unsignedChar: 0x00)
}

var test1 = Test()
var test2 = Test()　// 値を変えておく
test1=test2
```

上記で値は更新されるのですが、
test1の領域（アドレス）にtest2の中身が「=」でコピーされるということでしょうか。
以下と同意なのでしょうか。

```
test1.testUint8 = test2.testUint8
test1.testNSNumber= test2.testNSNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> test1の領域（アドレス）にtest2の中身が「=」でコピーされるということでしょうか。

コピーされるのは、「中身」ではなくて、**アドレス**です。なので、`test1`をあらかじめイニシアライズする必要はないです。

```
var test2 = Test()
var test1 = test2
```

アドレスのコピーなので、`test2`のプロパティの値に変更を加えると、`test1`のプロパティの値も変わります。同一のインスタンスを参照しているのですから、そうなります。

```
test2.testUint8 = 20
print(test1.testUint8) // 20
```

---

「memcopy()」が、「クラスのインスタンスを、バイト列としてコピーする」ことを意味する、クラスのインスタンスをバイト列としてコピーする方法を知りたいというのが、質問者さんの意図だとして、次の話をします。
あるいは、クラスのインスタンスを、参照のコピーでなく、実体のコピーをしたいという意図かもしれないので、それについても触れます。

バイト列を扱うには、Foundationフレームワークの`NSData`クラスを使います。純粋にSwiftだけ、とはいきません。インスタンスをバイト列に変換（エンコード）するには、クラスが`NSCodiong`プロトコルに準拠しているのが条件となります。

```
import Foundation

class TestClass: NSObject, NSCoding { // NSCodingを準拠。
    var value1: UInt8 = 0
    var value2: NSNumber = NSNumber(unsignedChar: 0)

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    // NSCodingに準拠すると必須になるイニシアライザ。アーカイブからデコードする処理を記述。
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.value1 = UInt8(aDecoder.decodeIntForKey("value1"))
        self.value2 = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("value2") as! NSNumber
    }

    // エンコードする処理を記述。
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeInt(Int32(value1), forKey: "value1")
        aCoder.encodeObject(value2, forKey: "value2")
    }

    // NSObjectのメソッド、copy()を有効にするための実装。
    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let object = TestClass()
        object.value1 = self.value1
        object.value2 = self.value2
        return object
    }
}

// 元インスタンスを作成。
let sample = TestClass()
sample.value1 = 100
sample.value2 = NSNumber(unsignedChar: 50)

// copy()メソッドによるコピー。
let sample1 = sample.copy()
print(sample1.value1) // 100
print(sample1.value2) // 50

// NSDataへの変換と、TestClassへ戻す変換（かつコピー）。
let theData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(sample)
let sample2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(theData) as! TestClass
print(sample2.value1) // 100
print(sample2.value2) // 50
```

いずれの形のコピーにしても、参照型のプロパティは、参照をコピーしても意味がなく、参照先の値のコピーをしなければいけないために、それ相応の処理を書かなければいけません。`memcpy()`1行だけで済むというわけにはいきません。

Comment: 「参照渡し」という言い方は通常メソッドや関数のパラメータの受け渡しについて使われるものなので、通常の変数やプロパティへの代入について「参照渡し」という言葉で説明するのはやめておいた方が良いのではないでしょうか。参照型の値を値渡しするなんて場合も多いので、混同の原因になるかと思います。

Comment: Harawoさん、Le Pere d'OOさん、回答ありがとうございます！
Harawoさんの実装を見て、わかるような、わからないような。。。
copy()内で、test2の値と同等のTest()オブジェクトを新たに生成し、それをtest2にコピーしている・・・と思うのですが、
その場合、test1の中身が書き換わるというよりも、test1のオブジェクト自体が入れ替わった（領域自体が変わった？）ように思えるのですが違うのでしょうか。

Comment: @harawo 話が逸れますが、オブジェクトのコピーを実装（NSCopyingに準拠）するには`copy`ではなく、`copyWithZone`メソッドを実装する必要があります。

Comment: @kanko 回答の内容をすべて書き換えました。ご期待に添えているかどうか、不安はありますが、ご覧ください。@La Pere d'OO ご指摘ありがとうございます。@kishukawa Katsumi `copyWithZone`を調べてみましたが、「話が逸れ」ているどころか、核心の話ですね。ご指摘に従い、回答内のコードを書き換えました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
頂いたコードを見ているのですが、まだ理解できておらず、もう少し時間をください。。。
（解決にできず申し訳ありません。）

Comment: ///copy()メソッドによるコピー。
上記についてですが、確認できました。なんとなくまだぼんやりとしているため、もう少し理解しなければと思います・・・
///SDataへの変換と、TestClassへ戻す変換（かつコピー）。
こちらのほうですが、まだ理解できておらず、合わせて勉強したいと思います。
中途半端な形ではありますが、頂いた回答から勉強していきたいと思います。